# Monitor individual process' network usage in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, software-rec

Is there a tool to monitor the network usage of individual processes for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Net Monitor](http://homepage.mac.com/rominar/net.html)
 it is not exactly what you want but it's helpful.

you can also see [this](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/09/15/how-to-monitor-your-internet-bandwidth-usage-in-os-x/).

Answer (score 1):

try [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/)